# How to create Expandable Forms?

Tags: java, android, forms, android-layout, expandablelistview

I need to create an `ExpandableListView` which contains Forms/Layouts.

Here how it should work.

The `ExpandableListView` contains 2 headings. *Contacts* and *Address*. When the user expand the *Contacts*, it should display the *Contacts* form. When the user expand the *Address* it should display the *Address* form.

These forms contain various things including `TextViews`, `EditTexts`, `ImageViews` etc. Most probably these will be in a `RelativeLayout` because they are forms, and you know, need to look professional.

I have tried many tutorials, including

1. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
2. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/
3. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

but didn't even find a clue.

My question is, how can I do this? There is no restriction such "I must use `ExpandableListView`", if this can be done in another way, I am ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following. create a layout that has the following:

1. A Heading or a textview with the label contacts
2. Below it a layout that has forms related to it
3. Add another textview below #2 and name it address
4. Add a layout below #3 .

The layout 2 and 4 will have visibility gone in the first case

When the user taps on layout 1, or the first textview, make layout 2 visible and vice versa. Do the same with the second textview.